# About the implementation of Java HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Why the capacity must be a multiple or 2?
Why use "&" in the indexFor functions?
Why recompute the hash in the hash function instead of directly using the key's hash code?

I think there are some important differences between the this implementation and the description on the "Introduction to Algorithm".

What does ">>>" mean?

```
static int hash(int h) {
        // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
        // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
        // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
        h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
        return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
}
```

Can anyone give me some guide ? I appreciate If some one can explain the hash algorithm.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I know using "&", the key can be mapped to the limited slots. What about influence to the collision in the hash map?

Comment: `>>>` is unsigned right shift.  Regular `>>` in Java will preserve and propagate the sign bit and leave a negative number negative.  `>>>` will fill the sign bit with zeros as shifting occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a performance optimization. The usual way to map a hash code to a table index is

```
table_index = hash_code % table_length;
```

The `%` operator is expensive. If `table_length` is a power of 2, then the calculation:

```
table_index = hash_code & (table_length - 1);
```

is equivalent to the (much) more expensive modulo operation.

Comment: This is why it's a good idea to learn to code in assembly on an old processor.

Comment: Danger Will Robinson! 50% of hash codes are negative numbers, so `hash_code % table_length` could be negative, resulting in an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. You need to use `Math.abs(hash_code % table_length)` to get a usable (ie safe) index

Comment: @Bohemian - Yes, negative numbers are an added complication. That's another advantage of the second method, which works just fine with negative hash code values.

Answer (score 0):

Pay no attention to the man behind the curtain.

The actual algorithm is no doubt a combination of "what feels good" to the developer, fixes for some odd degenerate cases, and simple tradition (for which users often develop obscure dependencies).

And note this:

> ```
>  * Applies a supplemental hash function to a given hashCode, which
>  * defends against poor quality hash functions.  This is critical
>  * because HashMap uses power-of-two length hash tables, that
>  * otherwise encounter collisions for hashCodes that do not differ
>  * in lower bits. Note: Null keys always map to hash 0, thus index 0.
> ```

Net: So long as it works and the performance is good, you don't care.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's answer. They are answered my question.